# Can our creativity create probability for reality? How legitimate is modal realism?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, metaphysics, metaphilosophy, reality, universe

That title is so wild but if you create say a cartoon and that universe. Does that open up the possibility that it exists somewhere in reality? Like it is now a universe that exists because you created it? These questions seem in line with [David Kellogg Lewis's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Lewis_(philosopher)) ideas about [modal realism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_realism).

**How legitimate is modal realism as a philosophical theory, and does it confuse "the universe" with subjective reality?**

Comment: If you haven't read them already, you might be interested in these links about [Many-worlds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation), [Many Worlds Theory](https://thereader.mitpress.mit.edu/the-many-worlds-theory/), and this argument for [possible worlds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Possible_world#Argument_from_ways). More in-depth material can be found at the [Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qm-manyworlds/). It is not necessarily that a thing is _created_, but its mere _possibility_  which some think might entail existence.

Comment: It depends on your metaphysical presuppositions. For an empiricist, there's only one demonstrable physical reality, and any putative universes in addition to our own are speculative at best and woo at worst.

Comment: Tweaked the tags and suggested language to address objection of opinion.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the arrow to reward the contributor and the checkmark to select what you feel is the best answer.

Comment: It's illegitimate, nothing else to say...